# RabbitMQ: Select queue by priority

Tags: php, rabbitmq

I'm using RabbitMQ in php, and have one consumer on two queues, `Q1` and `Q2`.
Since massages in `Q1` are more important I want them to be processed first.

**How to make the consumer consume from `Q2` only if there is no massages in `Q1`** ?

I use:

```
$channel->basic_consume('Q1', '', false, true, false, false, $callback);
$channel->basic_consume('Q2', '', false, true, false, false, $callback);
```

to attach the consumer to the queues. The result is that the consumer alternating between Q1 and Q2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think RabbitMQ will do what you want, the way you describe it. You would need to write code in your PHP to manage the "priority" for yourself, to do it this way.

But, I can think of two options to make it work with RabbitMQ and less code for you... both of which require you to do things a little different.

#### Option 1: create a separate consumer for Q1 and Q2.

Then it doesn't matter which one is more important, because they'll both be processed immediately.

The advantage here, is that you can scale out your consumers for Q1 easily. Just add more consumer instances, and you will process Q1 messages faster.

#### Option 2: Use the Priority Queue Support in RabbitMQ

https://www.rabbitmq.com/priority.html

This would require you sending all messages to the same Q, and setting a priority on them.

#### My Personal Choice: Option #1

I don't have a lot of experience with the Priority Queue support, because I don't see a lot of advantages of using that vs using separate queues and consumers. I like the ability to scale consumers and to have Q1 and Q2 use different message formats for different purposes.

Hope that helps!